# A python3 perspective on optional imports

Tags: python, import, importerror, pep

I have a python package which *can* use matplotlib help a user visualise what goes on during development, but for server deployment the visuals are completely unnecessary.

I was therefore thinking about being lenient on the requirements and define the importer as:

```
try:
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    enable_visuals = True
except ImportError:
    enable_visuals = False
```

and then in the few relevant functions add:

```
def visualise(self):
    if not enable_visuals:
        raise ImportError("visualise is not available unless matplotlib is installed")
```

Arguments pro/con on this pattern?

Comment: The visuals are all isolated in a single module. It's < 2 % of the code, but matplotlib 3x's the footprint.

Comment: How is ``visualise`` used? Is this part of some top-level namespace, e.g. ``my_package.standard_func`` alongside ``my_package.visualise``? Or is there some extra package exclusive to these helpers, e.g. ``my_package.debug.visualise``? Do users call `visualise` explicitly (i.e. write code that imports and uses it) or is there some frontend function that does it for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this pattern for your use case. It's a transparent way to indicate that visualization is disabled when the `matplotlib` package is not installed.

Your `visualise` function looks to me like something which could be nicely implemented as a decorator, allowing you to mark which functions require visualisation to be enabled like:

```
def visualise(func):                                                            
    def wrapper():                                                              
        if not enable_visuals:                                                  
            raise ImportError("visualise is not available unless matplotlib is installed")
        func()                                                                  
    return wrapper                                                              

@visualise                                                                      
def run(): 
    # This will only execute if enable_visuals is True, otherwise raises ImportError                                                             
    pass
```

In general, you might want to read up on how this [could mask some `ImportErrors`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262697/is-it-safe-to-catch-importerror-when-trying-to-import-optional-modules).